# mvc4 get List index in editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

For my project i need to know the index of the list element in an editor template to give this to a delete button.

For example i have a Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<TemplateModel> Words { get; set; }
    public Model()
    {
    }
}
```

a second Model with:

```
  public class TemplateModel
    {
        public int secondID { get; set; }
        public string word { get; set; }
        public TemplateModel()
        {
        }
    }
```

a View with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Words)
```

and a template with:

```
    @model TemplateModel
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.word)</p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.secondId)</p>
<p><input type="button" name="Index should be here"></p>
```

is it possible to get the index from the list for the button? mvc automatically created names like `Words[index]` but how is it transmitting the index and is it possible to use him?

**Update:**
I found a solution: 
In the CiewContext is a method to build the names of the elements. So it is also able use this and attach an own string. So i implement this in the editor template:

```
<input type="button" name="@ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Delete")"/>
```

and in html it will look like

```
<input type="button" name="Words[0].Delete">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template for the `List<TemplateModel>` try the following.

```
@model List<TemplateModel>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Word)</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SecondId)</p>
    <p><input type="button"  name="@(i)"></p>
}
```

Comment: In the template is no list anymore, so i can´t loop there. MVC automaticaly creates with the `@Html.TemplateFor` Helper a single template for every list element.

Comment: You can create your own template and use this one to access all the ids. try `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Words,"TemplateName")`.